# Get more than one line of data sent to browser

Tags: php, arrays, get

I have a form which transports data to another page using $_GET in PHP. In the browser on the other page, it shows all the data exported but when GET it into the page, it only shows the first line. I also want to be able to export only selected fields.

Below is my code,

```
    <?php do { ?>
  <form  action="../masspay/index.php" name="pile" method="GET" >
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" /></td>
    <td><input name="id" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_pile['id']; ?>" size="10" /></td>
    <td><input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" value="<?php echo $row_pile['amount']; ?>" size="10" /></td>
    <td><input name="amtnaira" type="text" id="amtnaira" value="<?php echo $row_pile['amtnaira']; ?>" size="13" /></td>
    <td><input name="acctno1" type="text" id="acctno1" value="<?php echo $row_pile['acctno1']; ?>" size="10" />
      (<?php echo $row_pile['accountname']; ?>)</td>
    <td><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" value="<?php echo $row_pile['phone']; ?>" size="13" /></td>
    <td><input name="staff" type="text" id="staff" value="<?php echo $row_admin['name']; ?>" size="15" /></td>
    <tr>
          <?php } while ($row_pile = mysql_fetch_assoc($pile)); ?>
         <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Process Selected" /></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

kk its looks like you have a database from where you are fetching the values and displaying it into values of text box.For sending the values you have to catch them on the index.php page
by doing

```
$_GET['id']
$_GET['name'] and furthor
 now for selected field set the value on the other page check the value of checkbox that it is checked or unchecked by assinging a variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending data like this? a [session](http://php.net/session) might be a better choice.

Anyway if the sql has more than one result the previous `_GET` values will be overwritten.

Try this:

```
  <?php do { ?>
  <form  action="../masspay/index.php" name="pile" method="GET" >
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="check" /></td>
    <td><input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_pile['id']; ?>" size="10" /></td>
    <td><input name="amount[]" type="text" id="amount" value="<?php echo $row_pile['amount']; ?>" size="10" /></td>
    <td><input name="amtnaira[]" type="text" id="amtnaira" value="<?php echo $row_pile['amtnaira']; ?>" size="13" /></td>
    <td><input name="acctno1[]" type="text" id="acctno1" value="<?php echo $row_pile['acctno1']; ?>" size="10" />
      (<?php echo $row_pile['accountname']; ?>)</td>
    <td><input name="phone[]" type="text" id="phone" value="<?php echo $row_pile['phone']; ?>" size="13" /></td>
    <td><input name="staff[]" type="text" id="staff" value="<?php echo $row_admin['name']; ?>" size="15" /></td>
    <tr>
          <?php } while ($row_pile = mysql_fetch_assoc($pile)); ?>
         <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Process Selected" /></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
```

The results of `$_GET['id']`, `$_GET['amount']`, etc will now be an array and contain all the sql results.

Since I don't know what you are doing on the receiving page I'm using [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r) so that you can see the structure of the data:

```
echo '<pre>'; // easier to read in a browser

echo 'Dump of checkbox: <br/>';
print_r($_GET['checkbox']);

echo 'Dump of id: <br/>';
print_r($_GET['id']);

echo 'Dump of amount: <br/>';
print_r($_GET['amount']);

echo 'Dump of acctno1: <br/>';
print_r($_GET['acctno1']);

etc ...

echo '</pre>';
```

The example output:

```
Dump of checkbox:
array(
    0 => 'check', // id 1 has been checked
    1 => '',      // id 2 has not been checked
),


Dump of id:
 array(
    0 => 1, // id 1
    1 => 2, // id 2
  ),


Dump of amount:
  array(
    0 => amount for id 1,
    1 => amount for id 2,
  )


Dump of acctno1:
  array(
    0 => acctno1 for id 1
    1 => acctno1 for id 2
  )

  etc ...
```

To check if the checkbox has be ticked:

```
// will return checked
if ($_GET['checkbox'][0] == 'check') {
    echo 'checked';
} else {
    echo 'not checked';
}

//will return not checked
if ($_GET['checkbox'][3] == 'check') {
    echo 'checked';
} else {
    echo 'not checked';
}
```

Update for comment:

```
$tt = ''.
foreach ($_GET['id'] as $key => $id) {
    $tt .= "$_GET['acctno1'][$key], $_GET['amount'][$key], not-private, order #$id. www.xxx.com, we hope to serve you often.<br/>";
}

echo $tt;
```

Comment: I would have used session but I wouldn't want it to timeout anytime cos it involves money...

Comment: How about the receiving page, it still give only first line and no clue on moving only selected. The code for the receiving page is: $acct = $_GET['acctno1'];
$amount = $_GET['amount'];
$id= $_GET['id'];

$tt = "$acct, $amount, not-private, order #$id. www.xxx.com, we hope to serve you often.";

$transferList = $tt;

Comment: I used the code like this and it did not work. Rather, I get this error on top of my page below the browser: check1449030.02 . Below is how I formated the code: print_r($_GET['checkbox']);

 array(
    0 => 'check', // id 1 has been checked
    1 => '',      // id 2 has not been checked
  );

 $id= print_r($_GET['id']);

 array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  );

 $amount= print_r($_GET['amount']);

  array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  );

 $acct= print_r($_GET['acctno1']);

  array(
    0 => 1
    1 => 2
  );

Comment: The receiving page code is an example of what would be returned by  `checkbox` `amount`, etc. Do not copy the arrays as they are example output from `print_r`. The reason I used `print_r` is so that you can see the structure of the data. Example Updated.

Comment: The second page is supposed to out put them one in a line for as many line like this: $tt = "$acct, $amount, not-private, order #$id. www.xxx.com, we hope to serve you often."; . To get $acct, it has to be something like $acct= $_GET['acctno1'];. The expected out put will be like this that is in 4 line U8586746, 0.01, not-private, www.xxx.com -we hope to serve you often
U8586546, 0.01, not-private, www.xxx.com -we hope to serve you often
U5586234, 0.01, not-private, www.xxx.com -we hope to serve you often
U8586980, 0.01, not-private, www.xxx.com -we hope to serve you often

Comment: Question: do you need to edit the values (i.e. amount, account number, etc) in the form or do you just want to select the results to show on the receiving page? New example

Comment: No need to edit it, just select the values to show in the receiving page.

Comment: I got errors and modified to this: **bold** `$tt ='';
foreach ($_GET['id'] as $key => $id) {
    $tt= "$_GET[acctno1][$key], $_GET[amount][$key], not-private, order $_GET[id][$key]. www.xxx.com, we hope to serve you often.<br/>"; Now am getting this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/root2/public_html/masspay/index.php on line 250
}`

Comment: Did you modify the form names to look like: `name="checkbox[]"`, `name="id[]"` `name="amount[]"`, etc

Comment: Yes I did: **bold** ` <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="check" /></td>
    <td><input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<?php echo $row_pile['id']; ?>" size="10" /></td>
    <td><input name="amount[]" type="text" id="amount" value="<?php echo $row_pile['amount']; ?>" size="10" /></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to select which results to show on the receiving page this is a better and safer way of doing it:

```
  <form  action="../masspay/index.php" name="pile" method="GET" >
   <tr>
    <?php while ($row_pile = mysql_fetch_assoc($pile)) { ?>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $row_pile['id']; ?>" /></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_pile['id']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_pile['amount']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_pile['amtnaira']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_pile['acctno1']; ?>(<?php echo $row_pile['accountname']; ?>)</td>
     <td><?php echo $row_pile['phone']; ?>></td>
     <td><?php echo $row_admin['name']; ?></td>
     <?php } ?>
     <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Process Selected" /></td>
   </tr>
  </form>
```

On the receiving page:

```
if (empty($_GET['checked']) {
    echo 'No results';
} else {

    $ids = array();
    foreach ($_GET['checked'] as $checked) {
        settype($checked, 'integer');
        $ids[] = "id = $id";
    }

    //Modify the sql used for the form to add this WHERE:
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $ids);

    $pile = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row_pile = mysql_fetch_assoc($pile)) { 
        echo "$row_pile['acctno1'] $row_pile['amount'], not-private, order #$row_pile['id'];. www.xxx.com, we hope to serve you often.<br/>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your reply gave me the inspiration but I have this issue. while ($row_pile = mysql_fetch_assoc($pile)) { 
        $tt= "$row_pile[acctno1] $row_pile[amount], not-private, order #$row_pile[id], www.xxx.com, we hope to serve you often.<br/>";
  echo "$row_pile[acctno1] $row_pile[amount], not-private, order #$row_pile[id], www.xxx.com, we hope to serve you often.<br/>";
    } In that code, the echo works fine giving more than one line but the $tt still gives only one line and the <br/> shows in the output. I only need the $tt. The echo is to test!

Comment: Before `while` Do this: `$tt = '';` and the `$tt` variable inside the `while` loop do this: `$tt .= "$row_pile['acctno1'] $row_pile['amount'] etc"; Note the dot equals.

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked but the <br/> did not work, everything is now in 1 line instead of seperate lines.